# Simeon Yetarian ( Random Event ) in 100% checklist

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I cleared the game, but I found that the Random Event mission Simeon Yetarian has to be done before misison Mr. Philips

Is it true that I have to start a new game in order to have 100% checklist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not true.

According to [the official GTA 5 checklist](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/career/checklist). you only need to complete 14 out of 57 random events in order to reach 100% completion. I know I got the 100% trophy without even knowing about the Simeon random event.

Comment: That's a valuable information! (though I want to complete them all)